# Email passed to Mail_mimeDecode() from MySQL query has goofed up characters for attachments

Tags: php, mysql, base64, mime

We have a database with stored mbox formatted emails, attachments in their native base64 format in the mailbox format. We can retrieve and access/parse all information...except for the attachments. In short, I can go into MySQL and actually see base64_encoded attachment data, but for whatever reason Mail_mimeDecode() structure shows the attachment portion like this:

````
[1] => stdClass Object
(
    [headers] => Array
    (
        [content-type] => image/gif; name="image.gif"
        [content-id] => <3243498760_6337281>
        [content-transfer-encoding] => base64
    )

    [ctype_primary] => image
    [ctype_secondary] => gif
    [ctype_parameters] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.gif
    )

    [body] => GIF89ahôÐÐÐðððÙÙ@àààòòÀ   ```000ßß`   PP
)
````

Any thoughts? Maybe it's the way I'm storing it, but if that were true, then I wouldn't be able to see actual base64 data when editing a row in phpMyAdmin. It's for that reason I'm suspecting something else happening.

**Additional Information**

1. I set the collation to: utf8_bin, so
   it's not case insensitive
2. I set the
   column type for the stored message
   to longtext, so there's enough space
   to hold most messages

**Updated Information**

Adding the flags suggested in the decode() function got me a base64 looking string, but it's only part of the string. As a test, I tried loading the exact same message from a file called "test.mbox" as opposed to MySQL. The loading via file worked great and showed me everything, but when doing it via MySQL I only see this. It's like it's truncating it and only shows one of the attachments (there are two in this message).

```
[1] => stdClass Object
(
    [headers] => Array
    (
        [content-type] => image/gif; name="image.gif"
        [content-id] => <3243498760_6337281>
        [content-transfer-encoding] => base64
    )

    [ctype_primary] => image
    [ctype_secondary] => gif
    [ctype_parameters] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.gif
    )

    [body] => R0lGODlhaAATAPQAANDQ0PDw8BAQENnZQODg4PLywCAgIGBgYDAwMN/fYKCgoJCQkFBQU
)
```

...when in actuality, it should look like this (from the "test.box" test I ran):

```
[1] => stdClass Object
(
    [headers] => Array
    (
        [content-type] => image/gif; name="image.gif"
        [content-id] => <3243498760_6337281>
        [content-transfer-encoding] => base64
    )

    [ctype_primary] => image
    [ctype_secondary] => gif
    [ctype_parameters] => Array
    (
        [name] => image.gif
    )

    [body] => R0lGODZhaAATAPQAANDQ0PDw8BAQENnZQODg4PLywCAgIGBgYDAwMN/fYKCgoJCQkFBQUHBw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)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprise! `Mail_mimeDecode` actually, well, I hesitate to say it, *decodes* the attachment.

BTW: longtext holding *most* email messages is an understatement I hope, that's 4GB, would hate to receive a mail bigger than that :)

Comment: Is there any way around this then? I'm wondering what the best way to structure this might be. Sorta lost right now with this :D

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve actually? There it is, your data ready to use in all it's original glory. If you want base64 encoded data, you either _don't_ decode it, or you use `base64_encode` to encode it again, which seems a waste. What are you planning to do with the data that you can't do with it either en- or decoded?

Comment: If you use [this package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mimedecode.decode.php), you could just do a `->decode(array('decode_bodies' => false));`

Comment: Hi Wrikken, you were spot on with the decoding going on. Thanks for the tip. I updated the original post with additional information. It's not decoding it, but it's truncating the first attachment's base64 code (although at least formatted correctly now) and entirely omitting the other attachments in the message. Any clue why this is getting so botched?

Comment: What is the format of the boundary & header lines and starting base64-encoded lines in the raw message (before mimedecoding, just the 'plain' string?)